# Set Kubectl aliases commands in PowerShell for SSH

Tags: powershell, ssh, alias, kubectl

Set Aliases for Kubectl commands. I am able to set the following alias for a ubuntu machine:

> alias k='kubectl'
>
> alias kg='kubectl get'
>
> alias kgpo='kubectl get pod' (many more..)

What I did: I opened the .bashrc file and added it there. So, now when I log in to this on-premise ubuntu box, I can use these awesome aliases.

My use case: I am a Windows user and using PowerShell to connect (SSH) ubuntu machines. Now, I would like to set these aliases in my windows PowerShell. So, I will not need to add these aliases for each on-premise ubuntu box. Please suggest.

Comment: To clarify some things. You want to connect via `gcloud compute ssh` using Cloud Tools for Powershell? I assume you've installed Cloud SDK. What you want to achieve is using gcloud to connect different Linux VMs and using kubectl commands in this Cloud Tools for powershell?

Comment: Sorry, we have on-premise ubuntu servers at our work.

Comment: Not using gcloud.

Comment: So you are connecting from on-prem Windows machine like mentioned in [this docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ssh-remoting-in-powershell-core?view=powershell-7.2) to On Prem Linux machine. You are not using any cloud resources?

Comment: @PjoterS That is correct. I have my local Windows laptop and connect to multiple different on-premise ubuntu servers.

Answer (score 0):

These days there is no explicit need/requirement to use an intermediary server to manage your Kubernetes clusters. Almost everything you need is already there in PowerShell or easily added without much effort.

First things first - If you haven't already you should go to the MS Store and install Windows Terminal Preview. Between WT and winget there is almost no need for choclatey, conemu, etc.

***Command completion:***
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/included/optional-kubectl-configs-pwsh/

***Aliases:***
There are a few really good blogs that have good examples -
https://manjit28.medium.com/powershell-define-shortcut-alias-for-common-kubernetes-commands-1c006d68cce2

There are way more than you could ever need here but great examples-   https://github.com/shanoor/kubectl-aliases-powershell

An example:

```
function GetPods([string]$namespace='kube-system') { kubectl get pods -n $namespace }
Set-Alias -Name kgp -Value GetPods
```

HTH - KarlV